# Linq to SQL and SQL Injection

Tags: linq-to-sql, sql-injection

What do I need to add, if I need to at all, to avoid sql injections?

```
public static Login GetLoginByName(string name)
{
    var context=new telephonyEntities1();

    Login t = (from l in context.Logins
               where l.login1==name
               select l).FirstOrDefault();
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linq-to-sql uses SqlParameter to generate SQL queries, so no you do not need to do anything extra.

From [Frequently Asked Questions (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386929.aspx)

> Q. How is LINQ to SQL protected from
>   SQL-injection attacks?
>
> A. SQL injection has been a
>   significant risk for traditional SQL
>   queries formed by concatenating user
>   input. LINQ to SQL avoids such
>   injection by using SqlParameter in
>   queries. User input is turned into
>   parameter values. This approach
>   prevents malicious commands from being
>   used from customer input.