# IQueryable LINQ provider and SQL injection?

Tags: linq, sql-injection, iqueryable

I'm working on a LINQ provider that uses the [IQ Toolkit](http://iqtoolkit.codeplex.com/) to tranlate LINQ queries to SQL queries. Are the classes provided by the IQ Toolkit safe from SQL injection attacks? If not, what I have to do to protect against SQL injection attacks, supposing that I'm using the IQ Toolkit and implementing my own LINQ provider. I read the [LINQ to SQL uses SqlParameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893743/linq-to-sql-and-sql-injection), 
 but it's still not clear to me what needs to be done with SqlParameter to protect against SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build your own provider, you must know that it is not that easy. Consider things like nested select, nested where, etc. There are great [blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2008/11/18/linq-links.aspx) on this topic.

But you are interested in protecting your database against SQL injection. So if you look at the sample code on this [page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/07/31/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-ii.aspx) and the `VisitConstant` method, that's the place where you run into constants of value type (string, int, etc.) or IQueryable.

Protection against SQL injections is not complicated, you just create new `SQLParameter` or you call method `DbProviderFactory.CreateParameter` described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory.createparameter.aspx). You will need some collection to store your parameters while you are traversing the expression tree. So the modified code will look like this:

```
protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression c) {
    IQueryable q = c.Value as IQueryable;
    if (q != null) {
        // assume constant nodes w/ IQueryables are table references
        sb.Append("SELECT * FROM ");
        sb.Append(q.ElementType.Name);
    }
    else if (c.Value == null) {
        sb.Append("NULL");
    }
    else {
        switch (Type.GetTypeCode(c.Value.GetType())) {
            case TypeCode.Boolean:
                param = dbProvider.CreateParameter();
                param.Name = "@param" + paramsList.Count;
                param.Value = (((bool)c.Value) ? 1 : 0;
                paramsList.Add(param);
                sb.Append(param.Name);
                break;
            case TypeCode.String:
                param = dbProvider.CreateParameter();
                param.Name = "@param" + paramsList.Count;
                param.Value = c.Value; // you don't have to care about escaping or formatting
                paramsList.Add(param);
                sb.Append(param.Name);
                break;
            ...
            case TypeCode.Object:
                throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("The constant for '{0}' is not supported", c.Value));
            default:
                sb.Append(c.Value);
                break;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

So while you are travesing the expression tree, you are building the SQL string and collecting the SQL parameters.

Comment: Thanks, that is quite a code snippet. I take it you have some experience with this.

Comment: I tried to create my own LINQ provider, but the task was very difficult... And there were other projects to play with;)

Answer (score 2):

From the blog [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/07/31/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-ii.aspx) it looks like IQ toolkit (or the initial version of the toolkit) is not safe from SQL injection attacks. But you can verify it by yourself - execute a query, capture the generated SQL and see if there are parameters used.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it would help if you could show how to use parameters with the LINQ provider to protect against SQL injection.